# JavaScript triple equals and three-variable comparison

Tags: javascript, triple-equals

Can somebody explain this?

```
1 == 1        //true, as expected
1 === 1       //true, as expected
1 == 1 == 1   //true, as expected
1 == 1 == 2   //false, as expected
1 === 1 === 2 //false, as expected
1 === 1 === 1 //false? <--
```

<s>Also is there a name for boolean logic that compares more than two numbers in this way (I called it "three-variable comparison" but I think that'd be wrong...)</s>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This expression:

```
1 === 1 === 1
```

Is evaluated as:

```
(1 === 1) === 1
```

After evaluating the expression inside parentheses:

```
true === 1
```

And that expression is logically false. The below expression returns `true` as expected though:

```
1 === 1 === true
```

Comment: Haha, should have tested more: `5 == 5 == 5` is also false, but because `1 == true` I was getting tripped up using my example of `1 == 1 == 1`. +1 thanks!

Comment: One more question: can I do what I want to do without a tedious expression (such as `x === y && y === z && x === z`)?

Comment: @DuncanNZ Are there always three variables involved?

Comment: yes - basically I need to check that 3 strings are all equal to eachother

Comment: @DuncanNZ You can work with the fact that `===` is transitive, so `x === y && x === z` would be enough.

Comment: so what is the shortest way to compare 3 variables?

Comment: @vsync Generally, to compare N distinct variables for equality (N > 1) you need N - 1 comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Equality is a [left-to-right precedence operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

So:

```
1 == 1 == 1
true == 1
true
```

And:

```
1 === 1 === 1
true === 1
false // because triple-equals checks type as well
```