# Javascript (-1 <= 5 <= 1) === true?

Tags: javascript, compare

I want to validate that a given number is within a given range:

```
function validate(min, max, amount) {
    return (min <= amount <= max);
}
```

But this does not seem to work properly. I know I can do it with two comparison and a logical AND, but I would like to it in one comparison. Is there any NATIVE javascript way to realize this?

Comment: Can't believe this is not a dupe, but the closest I could find was [JavaScript triple equals and three-variable comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15331947/1048572)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this instead :

```
return (min <= amount && amount <= max);
```

There is no shortcut. And there is a good reason the JavaScript engine can't guess your intent : what you typed was valid, it just isn't interpreted as you'd like. You were testing, in fact

```
((min <= amount) <= max)
```

and the result of the first comparison, which is a boolean, is converted to `0` or `1` for the second one ([more details here about operators precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), those comparison operators are left-to-right).

If you *really* want a shortcut, you could do this :

```
Number.prototype.isin = function(m,M) {
   return m<=this && this<=M; 
};

console.log(0.5.isin(1,2)); // logs false
console.log(3..isin(2,5));  // logs true
```

but I personally would use the standard solution with `&&` that everybody can read and which doesn't involve an additional function call.

Aside : I could have called my function `in` instead of `isin` but it might break ES3 browsers.

Comment: My alternative solution looks like what you posted. So there is no way to compare it like that?

Comment: @Luketep: "*there is no shortcut*"

Comment: http://wtfjs.com/2010/02/23/makes-perfect-sense > Remember how true sometimes has a value so in the above 3 > 2 evaluates to true making the second part of the expression evaluate true > 1 which is false. Of course! Thanks to void_0 for this one!

Answer (score 3):

**Operators ( == , <= , < , >= , == ) take only 2 arguments.**

When there are more arguments it uses mathematical order of computing. So in fact your code  behave like:

```
min <= amount  // true
true <= max // this is illogical
```

**It's also optimal**, because when executing logical statements and finding something like:

```
if(false && (some computing))
```

It will ignore `(some computing)` because result will be always `false`

**This is very common practive in every language.** Test like this will not have NullPointerException error, because first argument is already false.

```
if(obj != null && obj.getValue() > 10) //C++,Java, etc.

if(obj !== undefined && obj.val() > 10) // javascript
if(obj.length != 0 && obj.val() > 10) //jQuery
```